# Hive load data local - Where to store file

Tags: hive, load, local, filepath

I want to load data from a file stored in my computer. But I don't know in which repository I have to store my file.

When I stored in " My Documents" there is an error : "No file matching your path.....'

Comment: what is the query you used?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to put it on local filesystem on node with hadoop client. Then use Hive command `load data local inpath ...`  or put your file(s) directly to the table location using `hdfs dfs -put localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile` (specify your paths)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But where is the local file system on node with hadoop client ?

Comment: Any filesystem on node with Hadoop client. Local = not in hdfs

Comment: I put my file (client.csv) ony the following repository "D:\Profiles\akamalakumar\Documents" on my computer. How to specify the path in load data local inpath '?????'

Comment: Oh, finaly I got it... You are running it under Windows... Sorry, I do not know how to help you. Have never tried to run it on windows

Comment: Usually I use WinSCP to copy file to Linux folder. Also you can mount SMB folder